# How to place different JQuery codes in one line?

Tags: jquery, effects

How can I put this in one line?

```
$("#welcome").delay(100).fadeIn('slow').delay(100).$("#slogan").slideDown(1000);
```

The following code works:

```
$("#welcome").delay(100).fadeIn('slow').delay(100);
```

but not if I place the slogan code after it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use callback function of `delay()`

```
$("#welcome").delay(100).fadeIn('slow').delay(100, function(){
     $("#slogan").slideDown(1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it happens at the same time.

Comment: @Jordy: Did you try to refresh my answer?

Answer (score 2):

$.("#slogan") is not a method which you can chain after the rest of the methods...so no, this would not work. I guess what you want is to use a callback function like so:

```
$("#welcome").delay(100).fadeIn('slow').delay(100, function(){
   $("#slogan").slideDown(1000);
});
```

What this does is, call the slideDown for #slogan after the delay on #welcome is finished.

Comment: Ok, but how can I change the code that the #slogan would be slide down after the #welcome has fade in?

Answer (score 2):

by adding a anonymous function after the delay like this:

```
$("#welcome").delay(100).fadeIn('slow').delay(100, function() {$("#slogan").slideDown(1000) });
```

Answer (score 1):

The effects functions all take a callback optional argument:

```
 $("#welcome").delay(100).fadeIn('slow', function() {$("#slogan").delay(100).slideDown(1000);});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't append a second selector like that. If #slogan is a child of #welcome you can use

```
$("#welcome").delay(100).fadeIn('slow').delay(100).children("#slogan").slideDown(1000);
```

though.

Answer (score 0):

If slogan is a descenedant of welcome you could do:

```
$("#welcome").delay(100).fadeIn('slow').delay(100).find("#slogan").slideDown(1000);
```

Comment: Is there a difference between .find and .children in this context?

Comment: Find() searches all the descendants while children() only looks at childrens...i think children() is less "expensive" while with find() you are quite confident that your code keeps working even if the DOM structure changes a little